# You were kicked from the experience nil Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

It kicks me with coding this script.

```
function attach()
-- Will be called when a backdoor is found
notify("Backdoor Found")
settings.Found = true
STATUS.Text = "Attached: "..settings.BackdoorRemote:GetFullName()

for _, button in pairs(SIDEBAR:GetChildren()) do
    if button.ClassName == "ImageButton" and button ~= uiIndex.CurrentButton then
        button.ImageColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 255)
    end
end end
```

How?
I tried to attach it with my own gui button, when i press that button. it doesnt work, It kicks me with "nil" value.
Do not tell me ImageColor3, ImageButton, Color3, etc is not displayed
I want to exploit into my game. or Inactive Backdoored Games.
Like is there no argument or something?

Comment: what do you mean with "it kicks me with nil value"? is that your own interpetation of some error message? please share the actual text. as is your post doesn't make sense.
your code defines a function. it shouldn't cause anything like that until you call that function. where is that function called? provide more context

Comment: the next function is too long so i know attach does nothing but here is the [next function](https://pastebin.com/raw/gihh5Zsf) and its not my own interpetation, its just a error with nil reason.

Comment: wait wait wait isnt a backdoorremote added or what

Comment: "it's just a error with nil reason", what is that supposed to mean? errors come with information. they usually tell you what you attempted to do with that nil value, its name and a line and file location. you cannot just leave that away if you want help. you come to a doctor and say: "I'm in pain".  instead of saying: "my left big toe hurts since I kicked against a wall 3 days ago"